# Using express.js I get this error: Uncaught Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, express, routes

I'd like to get help with this issue.
The objective of this code is:

- Updates the `artist` with the specified artist ID using the information from the `artist` property of the request body and saves it to the database. Returns a 200 response with the updated artist on the `artist` property of the response body
- If any required fields are missing, returns a 400 response
- If an artist with the supplied `artist` ID doesn't exist, returns a 404 response.

Here is the route that fails:

```
artistsRouter.put('/:artistId', (req, res, next) => {
  if(areParamsRight(req.body.artist)){     // areParamsRight checks for the correct types and body's fields 
    db.serialize(() => {
      db.run('UPDATE Artist SET name = $name, date_of_birth = $date_of_birth, biography = $biography WHERE id = $iD',
                { $name: req.body.artist.name,
                  $date_of_birth: req.body.artist.dateOfBirth,
                  $biography: req.body.artist.biography,
                  $is_currently_employed: req.body.artist.isCurrentlyEmployed,
                  $iD: req.artist.id },                                       (error) => { if(error) { next(error) }
      });
      db.get(`SELECT * FROM Artist WHERE id = $thisId `, { $thisId: req.artist.id } , (err, artist) => {
        if(err){
          next(err);
        } else {
          res.status(200).send(artist);
          console.log('response sent. ')
        }
      })
    })
  } else {
    res.setStatus(400);
  }
});
```

I've tried the following:

- Using .serialize() to avoid race condition.
- Verified that the SQL works.
- Verified the type of data in the request.
- Checked that req.artist.id is attached.
- Dividing the route:

```
artistsRouter.put('/:artistId', (req, res, next) => {
  if(areParamsRight(req.body.artist)){   
    db.serialize(() => {
      db.run('UPDATE Artist SET name = $name, date_of_birth = $date_of_birth, biography = $biography WHERE id = $iD',
                { $name: req.body.artist.name,
                  $date_of_birth: req.body.artist.dateOfBirth,
                  $biography: req.body.artist.biography,
                  $is_currently_employed: req.body.artist.isCurrentlyEmployed,
                  $iD: req.artist.id }, (error) => { if(error) { next(error) }
      });
      next();
    })
  } else {
    res.setStatus(400);
  }
});

artistsRouter.put('/:artistId', (req, res, next) => {
  db.get(`SELECT * FROM Artist WHERE id = $thisId `, { $thisId: req.artist.id } , (err, artist) => {
    if(err){
      next(err);
    } else {
      res.status(200).send(artist);
      console.log('response sent. ')
    }
  })
})
```

Below the helper function. It seems to work OK because it is also used in a POST route .

```
// this function will accept req object and will return true if params are the proper type.
function areParamsRight(obj) {
  const name = obj.name, dateOfBirth = obj.dateOfBirth, biography = obj.biography;

  if( Object.keys(obj).includes('name' && 'dateOfBirth' && 'biography')
   && typeof name === 'string' && typeof dateOfBirth === 'string' && typeof biography === 'string' ){
    return true;
  } else return false;
}
module.exports = areParamsRight;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does `areParamsRight()` do?"  Please show that code.

Comment: I've edited the post. What you have asked for is at the end.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code can cause two responses to be sent when there is an error with the database call:

```
  db.run('UPDATE Artist SET name = $name, date_of_birth = $date_of_birth, biography = $biography WHERE id = $iD',
            { $name: req.body.artist.name,
              $date_of_birth: req.body.artist.dateOfBirth,
              $biography: req.body.artist.biography,
              $is_currently_employed: req.body.artist.isCurrentlyEmployed,
              $iD: req.artist.id }, (error) => { if(error) { next(error) }
  });
  next();
```

If you format it in a way that makes the code flow a little more clear like this:

```
artistsRouter.put('/:artistId', (req, res, next) => {
    if (areParamsRight(req.body.artist)) {
        db.serialize(() => {
            db.run('UPDATE Artist SET name = $name, date_of_birth = $date_of_birth, biography = $biography WHERE id = $iD', {
                $name: req.body.artist.name,
                $date_of_birth: req.body.artist.dateOfBirth,
                $biography: req.body.artist.biography,
                $is_currently_employed: req.body.artist.isCurrentlyEmployed,
                $iD: req.artist.id
            }, (error) => {
                if (error) {
                    next(error)
                }
            });
            next();
        })
    } else {
        res.setStatus(400);
    }
});
```

You can see that as long as `areParamsRight()` returns true, then the code will always execute `db.run()` and then call `next()`.  But, if there's an error in the `db.run()`, then the code will also call `next(error)`.  But since that would get called asynchronously, the call to `next()` has already executed and this would be trying to send a second response to the same request and thus can generate the type of error you see (trying to send two responses to the same request).

It's a bit confusing what the desired behavior would be here.  First, you only want to send one response, not two.  But, since this is a `.put()` request handler and not a middleware handler, it seems like you should be sending a response here rather than calling `next()`.  I would think is should probably be this:

```
artistsRouter.put('/:artistId', (req, res, next) => {
    if (areParamsRight(req.body.artist)) {
        db.serialize(() => {
            db.run('UPDATE Artist SET name = $name, date_of_birth = $date_of_birth, biography = $biography WHERE id = $iD', {
                $name: req.body.artist.name,
                $date_of_birth: req.body.artist.dateOfBirth,
                $biography: req.body.artist.biography,
                $is_currently_employed: req.body.artist.isCurrentlyEmployed,
                $iD: req.artist.id
            }, (error) => {
                if (error) {
                    next(error);                // report error
                } else {
                    res.sendStatus(200);        // report success
                }
            });
        })
    } else {
        res.sendStatus(400);
    }
});
```

Note also that you had `res.setStatus(400)` at the end and I think you meant `res.sendStatus(400)`.

Note: Since you are only running one database query here in this route handler, it does not seem like you need to be wrapping things in `db.serialize()`.  But, I am not an expert in SQL.

Comment: The code you have checked is an attempt to solve the issue. Above you see the main option (first block of code), where there's no `next()` call except for the case there's an error. And yes, it should be only one response but the code must perform 2 querys, 1 for updating the table and the 2nd for getting the updated record. I've checked that synchronicity is not a problem by using `serialize()`. Sorry if I am not properly understanding your answer. I appreciate it. BTW I've fixed the `sendStatus()` part. I updated the post at the beginning to specify goals. Should 've done that before, sorry.

Comment: @jSamsa - Well, I can't help you further if you don't show the real code without leaving anything out.  Your question only shows one database operation.  The problem is likely in the coordination between your two operations, but you've not shared that code.